# Are there any ways to set disk size limit for each docker container?

Tags: docker, limit, disk

The devicemapper has been removed from Docker v25.0. And the Docker plugin convoy was archived as well.

Are there any ways to set disk size limit for each docker container?

All the information I found is about the devicemapper.

I'm would like to limit the disk size to each container. For example, a Ubuntu container should not use more than 20GB, and at the same time a nginx container should not use more than 5GB.